# Google Places API - Next Page Token returning same results

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-places-api

I'm using the Google Places API to output the names of restaurants in a table view. I've been able to parse the JSON and get the names and pictures of the places. However, the table view contains only 20 results. So I found out that I needed to use the next_page_token, that's provided, to get the rest of the data. However, when I get the next_page_token and put it inside the request URL, the data from the first query is repeated multiple times inside the table view. 
    '

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    var location : CLLocation? = locations.last

    var searchURL = NSString(format: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=50.940463,-114.077553&radius=50000&type=restaurant&key=MY_API_KEY") as? String

    callAlamo(url: searchURL!)
}    

func callAlamo(url:String){

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in

        self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
    })
}

// PARSING JSON DATA FOR GETTING NAME AND PICTURE OF PLACES AND GETTING LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE

func parseData(JSONData:Data){

    do{
        var myReadableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStandard

        // PARSING THROUGH JSON DATA TO GET NAMES AND PICTURES OF PLACES, THEN PUTTING 
        // THEM INTO AN ARRAY AND OUTPUTTING THEM ONTO TABLE VIEW CELL

        if let results = myReadableJSON["results"] as? [JSONStandard]{
            for i in 0..<results.count{

                let item = results[i]
                print("Item is: ",item)
                let names = item["name"] as! String

                placeNames.append(names)

                // GETTING PHOTO URL WITH photo_reference AND PUTTING THEM INTO imageURL ARRAY

                if let photos = item["photos"] as? [JSONStandard]{

                    for k in 0..<photos.count{

                        let photo = photos[k] as JSONStandard

                        let photoRef = photo["photo_reference"] as! String

                        let photoURL = NSString(format: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=%@&key=MY_API_KEY", photoRef) as? String
                        imageURL.append(photoURL!)
                    }
                }

                if let geometry = item["geometry"] as? JSONStandard{
                    if let location = geometry["location"] as? [String : Any]{

                            let latitude = location["lat"] as? Double
                            let longitude = location["lng"] as? Double
                    }
                }
            }

            // CHECK TO SEE IF JSON DATA CONTAINS next_page_token. IF IT DOES, REPEAT PROCESS OF 
            // PARSING THROUGH JSON DATA AND GET SECOND PAGE OF DATA. REPEAT UNTIL LAST PAGE
            // DOESN'T CONTAIN next_page_token.

            if (myReadableJSON["next_page_token"] != nil){

                nextPageToken = myReadableJSON["next_page_token"] as! String
                let nextPageGoogleURL = NSString(format:"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?pagetoken=%@&key=MY_API_KEY",nextPageToken ) as String
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    self.callAlamo(url: nextPageGoogleURL)

                }
            }
            // SHOULD BE PLACED AT THE END OF GATHERING DATA
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            imageURL.removeAll()
            placeNames.removeAll()
        }
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I was able to figure out the solution to my problem. Thanks to this other thread on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942155/google-places-web-service-how-to-get-next-page-of-results-in-swift-3).

I just had to add an if let condition inside my parseData() function, but keep it outside of the loop and add a timer delay, as is mentioned in an answer from the provided SO query, there is a time delay between when the next_page_token is issued, and when you can access that data. So I added a slight time delay. 
    `

```
func parseData(JSONData:Data){

    do{
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStandard

        placeNames.removeAll()

        if let results = readableJSON["results"] as? [JSONStandard]{
            print("JSON: ",results)
            for i in 0..<results.count{

                let item = results[i]
                let names = item["name"] as! String

                placeNames.append(names)

                if let geometry = item["geometry"] as? JSONStandard{
                    if let location = geometry["location"] as? [String : Any]{

                         self.latitude = (location["lat"] as? Double)!
                         self.longitude = (location["lng"] as? Double)!
                    }
                }

                let marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude))
                marker.icon = UIImage(named: "locationMarker")
                print(placeNames[i],"\n")
                marker.title = placeNames[i]
                marker.snippet = "Nothing"
                marker.map = self.googleMapsContrainer
            }
        }

        if let pageToken = readableJSON["next_page_token"]{

            let newURL = NSString(format:"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?pagetoken=\(pageToken)&key=MY_API_KEY" as NSString) as? String


            let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: { 

                self.callAlamo(url: newURL!)
            })

        }
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally google returns upto 20 places in the result(each search can return as many as 60 results), if the search consist of more than 20 results then you will get ***next_page_token*** in your response object, if next_page_token is **nil** or is not returned, then there are **no further results.**

sample response object
`

```
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CqQCEQEAANi9ziRMdWd-lHhBE1Mhr6S7wqt_97liE5q42J3heMg6XqL2vwdOClJa5_YzdZmtLmhe_QFimH6y6a0dUXSXRYMXXMG2lemTCoQYYhRF7py9tafUrqILe5spsUBTMDbI9-mJUjY548lH0c7oX8NH-V3KH4VuDRA-6opxF0_IG5Z0bbzPz9-q2OhmkW9IS3w_rH1jKtTJiOSYljM6ZSJh7jSZi_dx76qtN8hxhE4trrFKLGO1WfHmjBWo506Qi5bANLikIs0qtkbYzBqu2AjYIJp-dpA7rAVWLKHWUi7Vs6oEYI_L_iqr7JODDF4XkTyjg2U_2rPxbgRR8RV6GUt-rZ1R8nEJLVrYA0LBYsZdJd",
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.8709434,
               "lng" : 151.1903114
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8694072197085,
                  "lng" : 151.1917756802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8721051802915,
                  "lng" : 151.1890777197085
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "e644f7f34cf875b9919c6548f1b721947362850a",
         "name" : "Lunch Cruise with Jazz on Sydney Harbour",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 292,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105423912060796272053/photos\"\u003eLunch Cruise with Jazz on Sydney Harbour\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRYAAAA0X0ax8-an2n_73VHZ-oHXfnJMId06BSZwJWwTqGPL2FtzZIIt--PyUhyEByzew0dyAS85yAPWn-gPdVfMOuPnHiThkRMPntdbWSRcIA9Vm9vAqQx9RWfVBg21Xf2ePfAEhCfYg0Rz46AvyL4XopycJJeGhQh_eFhP7pQXd1LGezkVW4gpat3AA",
               "width" : 438
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJLfySpTOuEmsRPCRKrzl8ZEY",
         "rating" : 3,
         "reference" : "CmRRAAAAACfGiWX6r6IcOaFJBLN1VY3XdxLD4zUufz7sjPHMfIdzGa4ZycRoZyCJbGis42HZnxLC5b28TbMvfaVsDBcck5DDuv39sdq4w2q1dU0Z5rtmFGsXeFaRrdo36jIMlMEaEhC3grmYSOAnDyGektJCIxbrGhQwyyGsW0OiItrqFtKzazRcEDE-EQ",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "night_club",
            "bar",
            "restaurant",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "37 Bank Street, Pyrmont"
      },
.
.
.
"status": "OK"
}`
```

sample url for pagination request should consist of pagetoken as parameter
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY&pagetoken=Xyz

refer [Google places Api](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Are you saying that the request URL I have created is an incorrect format? Because, I put the URL into a web browser and I was able to get the remainder of the results.

Comment: What i mean is that your search result does not consist of more than 20 results, hence there is no next_page _ token in the response, try new coordinates or keyword, if you still don't obtain desired results give me the coordinates or keywords you are searching for

Comment: From your edit I think that you should append the api key at the end of the URL and append the next page token only if it's not nil, also when making fresh request don't spend the next page token

Comment: Provide the coordinates you are searching for and also double check the google places api key

Comment: I've updated my code with the location coordinates.

Forgive me, but am I not already appending the API key at the end of the URL and also checking if the next page token is nil, if (myReadableJSON["next_page_token"] != nil), if the condition is true then take the next page token and place it in the request URL and call the method again.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. I have added an update to my question with my solution. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

For other people who might find this problem, in my case i was making the mistake of sending `next_page_token=` as the url parameter, but the correct parameter to send is `pagetoken=`