# Google places web service: How to get next page of results in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, google-api

I'm using the Google Web Service API in my iOS app to find hospice locations near the user's location.  I can get the first page of results, but have been unsuccessful with using the pagetoken to retrieve the next page of results.  Below is my search function.  Any help on where I am going wrong (have never used URLSession before) would be appreciated.

```
func performGoogleQuery(url:URL)
{
    print("PERFORM GOOGLE QUERY")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("An error occured: \(error)")
            return
        }

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]

            // Parse the json results into an array of MKMapItem objects
            if let places = json?["results"] as? [[String : Any]]
            {
                print("Places Count = \(places.count)")     // Returns 20 on first pass and 0 on second.

                for place in places
                {
                    let name = place["name"] as! String
                    print("\(name)")

                    if let geometry = place["geometry"] as? [String : Any]
                    {
                        if let location = geometry["location"] as? [String : Any]
                        {
                            let lat = location["lat"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                            let long = location["lng"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
                            let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate)
                            let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
                            mapItem.name = name
                            self.mapitems.append(mapItem)

                        }
                    }
                }
                print("mapItems COUNT = \(self.mapitems.count)")    // Remains at 20 after 2 passes.
            }
            // If there is another page of results, 
            // configure the new url and run the query again.
            if let pageToken = json?["next_page_token"]
            {
                let newURL = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?pagetoken=\(pageToken)&key=\(self.googleAPIKey)")
                //print("PAGETOKENURL = \(newURL)")

                self.performGoogleQuery(url: newURL!)
            }
        }catch {
            print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
        }
    })
     task.resume()
}
```

> Update (Based on Dima's response):  Change
>   self.performGoogleQuery(url: newURL!)

to this

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
                        self.performGoogleQuery(url: newURL!)
            }
```

Comment: Dima's solution worked.  I added a delay before recursively calling performGoogleQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation:](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests)

> There is a short delay between when a next_page_token is issued, and
>   when it will become valid.

I think you are probably fetching the next page too quickly. Try to set a delay of at least a few seconds and see if that solves your issue.

From what I see though, I don't think you're meant to automatically fetch pages in quick succession. They seem to want you to let the user trigger fetching of additional content.

> You can request a new page up to two times following the original
>   query. Each page of results must be displayed in turn. Two or more
>   pages of search results should not be displayed as the result of a
>   single query.